# CSS - Connecting Two Classes

Tags: html, css

My Code.
HTML -

```
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
     <li><a href="#"><img src="images/icons/home.png" />HOME</a></li>
     <li><a href="#"><img src="images/icons/about.png" />ABOUT US</a></li>
     <li><a href="#"><img src="images/icons/pricing.png" />PRICING</a></li>
     <li><a href="#"><img src="images/icons/info.png" />WHY INSIGNE?</a></li>
  </ul>
</div> <!--menu end-->
```

CSS

```
.curves3 {
   border-radius:3px;
   -moz-border-radius:3px;
   -webkit-border-radius:3px;
   -ms-border-radius:3px;
}
#menu li a {
   background:#6fb6e5;
}
```

So that's my HTML and CSS. What i wanna do is, i wanna connect `.curves3` class to the `#menu li a`. I don't wanna add `class="curves3"` to all the `<a>` tags, neither i wanna copy those  border-radius to `#menu li a`. I just wanna connect them. Is there any way? Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you want to just copy the `border-radius` to the `#menu li a`? It's simple. It works. You'd be done by now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use, jquery code like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#menu li a').addClass('curves3');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$("#menu ul li a").each(function() {
$(this).addClass( "foo" );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

With only CSS you can't reuse the class the way I think you want to.  You would have to copy the styles or add the class in the html or via Javascript.

You could easily do this in LESS or SASS with the use of a mixin.  If you were interested in using a CSS Pre-Processor.

http://lesscss.org/